# Counting number of times column switches values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

**Input:**

```
domain      ip     time
Google      101    2020-03-31 14:55:37  
Google      101    2020-03-31 14:56:12  
Facebook    101    2020-03-31 14:57:36  
Amazon      101    2020-03-31 14:57:45  
Yahoo       102    2020-02-28 12:15:15  
Yahoo       102    2020-03-01 15:20:12  
Hotmail     102    2020-03-02 14:52:31
```

I want to get the following output where I create the column `switches`. It basically counts the number of time an IP switches domains.
For example IP 101 went from Google to Facebook to Amazon, so it switches twice (we don't count the first domain). Assuming the data is all ordered how do I get the following output in SQL Server?

**Expected Output**

```
domain      ip     time                  switches
Google      101    2020-03-31 14:55:37   2
Google      101    2020-03-31 14:56:12   2
Facebook    101    2020-03-31 14:57:36   2
Amazon      101    2020-03-31 14:57:45   2
Yahoo       102    2020-02-28 12:15:15   1
Yahoo       102    2020-03-01 15:20:12   1
Hotmail     102    2020-03-02 14:52:31   1
```

Comment: I don't really follow; why does `ip` `102` have a value of `1`? didn't they switch from Yahoo to Hotmail? What would you expect if `ip` `101` went back to Google after facebook?

Comment: IP 102 has a value of 2 because it only switched once to Hotmail. IP 101 has a value of 2 because it switched twice - once to Facebook then once again to Amazon. If IP 101 switched to Google after Facebook the value would be 3. Because it switches from Google to Facebook to Google to Amazon (we don't count google because it starts at google).

Comment: `select domain, count(distinct ip)-1 switches from tbl group by domain` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count switching back to a previous value (as opposed to distinct values), you'll need to use `LAG`:

```
with cte (domain, ip_addr, time_col) as
(
select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:55:37'
UNION select 'Google',101,'2020-03-31 14:56:12'
union select 'Facebook',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:36'
union select 'Amazon',101,'2020-03-31 14:57:45'
)

select
domain,
ip_addr,
time_col,
sum(switches) over (partition by ip_addr) -1
from (
select *,
case when lag (domain) over (partition by ip_addr order by time_col) = domain then 0 else 1 end as switches
    
from cte
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count statement with partition by -- since you want times changed then you want 1 less than the count so substract 1.

```
SELECT domain, ip_addr, time_col, 
    (COUNT(domain) OVER (partition by ip_addr)) - 1 as switches
FROM tableyoudidnotname
```